# Does IPMI-DCMI power consumption include GPU?

Tags: electrical-power, ipmi

I'm using FreeIPMI to measure power consumption with `--get-system-power-statistics` on servers which contain GPUs. Will the returned power consumption in watts include that of the GPUs? The documentation is a bit vague on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

FreeIPMI maintainer here.  The `ipmi-dcmi` command's `--get-system-power-statistics` command comes from the "Get Power Reading" command in the DCMI specification.  Unfortunately, the description in the DCMI specification is equally vague, so it's likely just up to the implementer.